# How can I open Chrome with my default account logged in with selenium? I tried it in a lot of ways but it didn't work for me

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:/Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome/User Data\Default")

chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Josh_files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path), options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Above is the code. When it opens chrome it is not logged in with my default account. Why is that, how could I do it?